# Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Tengo el siguiente error que sucede en varias páginas .aspx:
1 - En la página mantenimiento.aspx cuando le doy ejecutar en Visual Studio directamente me muestra el siguiente error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Argumento de devolución o de
>   devolución de llamadas no válido. La validación de eventos se habilita
>   usando  en la configuración o <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> en una página. Por motivos de
>   seguridad, esta característica comprueba que los argumentos pasados a
>   eventos de devolución o de devolución de llamadas se origina desde el
>   control del servidor que inicialmente los procesó. Si los datos son
>   válidos y son los que se esperaba, utilice el método
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation para registrar los
>   datos de devolución o de devolución de llamadas para su validación.

En el codebehind lo que tengo es esto:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                cargarAlbumes();
                cargarBandas();
                cargarBandasDDList();
                noMostrarBotones();
                //noTienePermiso();
            }               
        }

  private void cargarAlbumes()
    {
        lstAlbumes.DataSource = new gestoraAlbum().obtenerTodos();
        lstAlbumes.DataTextField = "datos";
        lstAlbumes.DataValueField = "id";
        lstAlbumes.DataBind();
    }

   private void cargarBandas()
    {
        lstBandas.DataSource = new gestoraBanda().obtenerTodos();
        lstBandas.DataTextField = "datos";
        lstBandas.DataValueField = "id";
        lstBandas.DataBind();
    }

private void cargarBandasDDList()
{
    ddlBandaAlta.DataSource = new gestoraBanda().obtenerTodos();
    ddlBandaAlta.DataTextField = "nombre";
    ddlBandaAlta.DataValueField = "id";
    ddlBandaAlta.DataBind();
}
```

Hay un botón llamado `btnMantenimientoAlbumes`que al hacer click sobre el mismo deberá poner como `true` el estado visible del panel que tiene los listBox, dropDownList entre otros.

Ya he probado escribiendo `EnableEventValidation = "false"` y si bien no es recomendable hacerlo de esa forma, es de la única que me ha funcionado hasta ahora.

Lo mismo me pasa en el formulario del login en el cual cuando hago click en el botón "Ingresar" directamente me muestra el error, ya puse un punto de interrupción en el botón pero ni siquiera llega hasta ahí. ¿alguna sugerencia? gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creé una página .aspx nueva y le coloqué un botón que lo único que hace es redirigir a otra página y es cuando le doy click al botón que me da ese error. El código del click del botón lo único que tiene es `Response.Redirect("inicio.aspx");`

Comment: Después de pasar días buscando la solución, dí con que en la master page había una etiqueta `form` la cual no debería de estar ahí y al dejarla comentada el sitio funciona no da ese error.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo error hace poco. Estaba llamado un metodo fuera de las etiquetas form:

```
<form runat="server">
</form>
<button onserverclick="ejemplo"></button>
```

De estar adentro

```
<form runat="server">
<button onserverclick="ejemplo"></button>
</form>
```